# ontaskchanged event is not triggered in a moss state machine workflow

Tags: workflow, 2007, infopath

I have this workflow which was working fine. But now it does not.

It has the following states -inital, stage1, stage2, stage3, final. Initial stage works properly. In stage1, create task also works perfectly. So when I edit the task form and submit nothing happens. The OnTaskChanged event is not at all triggered. And the workflow simply hangs like that.

Made all possible checks and still could not identify the problem here. Can any one please help me with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be with our testing environment. Not sure what it is though.
As it is the workflow works perfectly on the live environment. Can anyone help me to identify the issue on the testing environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Tasks list. Deleted the existing tasks list and created a new one. Now the workflow works perfectly.